# Tenho algum risco em utilizar parentActivity no manifest do meu aplicativo android?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Eu tenho uma activity com um texto sobre termos de uso. Ele pode ser chamado através de um menu e aberto diretamente. Então por esse motivo eu coloquei no manifest esta activity em **parentActivityName** para que quando ele é aberto apareça a seta para voltar a tela principal.

Ficou desta forma:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityTerms"
        android:label="Declarações Legais"
        android:parentActivityName=".ActivityMain" />
```

Agora depois de semanas desenvolvendo, percebi que preciso chamar esta mesma activity em um botão na tela de cadastro, e alguns outros lugares da aplicação.

Então ele deixa de ser parente apenas da tela principal, e passa a ser de varias outras telas.

Até então eu fiz uns testes, e funcionou normalmente, mesmo q a seta apareça e a tela não é parente dela, ao clicar ela está voltando para a tela anterior normalmente.

Agora eu pergunto... será que posso ter problemas futuros em utilizar deste modo? Será que não terei problemas em outros tipos de dispositivos?

Pq no meu celular e no emulador funciona normal, mas meu medo é quando o aplicativo ser lançado, começar a dar algum erro por conta disto. Corro algum risco?

Comment: Não me ocorre qualquer problema. A que tipo de problema se refere?

Comment: @ramaral, não sei, de repente algum bug, ou conflito em algum dispositivo que leve o manifest ao pé da letra. O que na verdade deveria neh. Ja que colocamos de quem a activity é parent, e o botão de retornar se baseia nisso, é até estranho ele aceitar que eu chame a activity por outro lugar e mesmo assim o botão de voltar funcione normalmente. Pelo menos nos dispositivos que testei até agora ta tudo ok.

Comment: A seta no canto superior esquerdo(no Toolbar) faz retornar para `parentActivityName`. A tecla *back* faz retornar para a Activity que a chamou.

Comment: @ramaral Então algo esta acontecendo errado no meu aplicativo, pq tanto pela seta quanto pela tecla back, esta voltando pra activity q chamou mesmo eu tendo setado a parentActivityName no manifest. 
A unica diferença que está acontecendo, é que quando eu vou pela tecla back ele simplesmente fecha, e volta sem recriar, mas quando vou pela seta, ele fecha, mas recria a Activity anterior novamente.

Comment: Veja se está a fazer tudo como descrito em [Adding an Up Action](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action.html). Tenha atenção à nota que refere o uso em dispositivos com Android inferior a 4.1.

Comment: Então eu dei uma lida la, e por enquanto esta tudo direitinho conforme a documentação. Acho que não vou ter nenhum problema futuro. Vou desencanar disso então. Muito obrigado pelas respostas @ramaral